# firebase deleting a document deletes its subcollections in console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm confused when I read [firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents) says that :

> Deleting a document does not delete its subcollections!

but this isn't the normal in the `firebase console` now, I can see when I delete a doc from the console all subcollections that belong to it also gone.

on the other side, the `firebase emulator` doesn't delete the subcollection and just remove any existing fields on the doc and keep the subcollections in place

Answer (score 2):

I think  they was referring to giving end user the permission to delete data  directly in your app and think it will be a more secure way if they delete data from the app through a Callable function that can be call recursively
Hope this help  clearly your doubt

Comment: That's indeed it: the Firestore APIs are shallow both in reads (they don't auto-read data from subcollections) and on deletes (they don't auto-delete subcollections). The console indeed *does* recursively delete data from subcollections, as can the Firebase CLI.